# calling superclass' overrideen function using base class objects in java

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding

Suppose I have one superclass `Test` with a `display()` method and another class named `Test1` which extends class `Test` and this class also a method named `display()`.

Now I have one another class named `DemoClass` which has a `main` method in it. Now in `main` method I create a object of sub class 'Test1' and wish to call a overridden method of the superclass, i.e. `display()` of class 'Test'.

And I don't want to do any changes to subclass or superclass. How can I do it by only making changes in the `main` method?

Comment: please provide the code which you are working on. Its totally confusing this way.

Comment: I think the only way to do it is using reflection.. which is not generally a good idea.

Comment: Can u help me with reflection way of getting my thing done, it would be very kind of u.

Answer (score 4):

You can't. You will need to change Test or Test1 if you want to be able to call Test.display from DemoClass.

You could create a new method in Test1 to call it, like this:

```
    public void displayTest() {super.display();}
```

or rename one of the methods.

Comment: This was the question asked by my seniors and he said that it is possible , you just have to make a little change in the main method and he clearly said that you are not allowed to make any change in the existing super class or subclass code.

Comment: Or just don't override it and the super method will be called anyways..

Comment: Are you allowed to change Test1 to Test in DemoClass? (e.g. "new Test().display()")

Comment: @user3056354 - immibis is right.. You cant.. The method which is called depends on the type of object , and here you are calling display() on an instance of Test1. So, display() of Test1 will be called. the only way to call display() of Test is use super(). Otherwise you will have to create an object of Test() instead of Test1.